# mongodb: How to use variable inside group operator in aggregate operation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am tring to make a query where use the value and try to interpolate a string in a new field.

Mongo Database:

```
    [
  {
    "state": "1",
    "events": {
      "1": [
        {
          "date": 123.2,
          "msg": "msg1"
        },
        {
          "date": 124.2,
          "msg": "msg2"
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          "date": 125.2,
          "msg": "msg3"
        },
        {
          "date": 126.2,
          "msg": "msg4"
        }
      ],
      
    }
  },
  {
    "state": "2",
    "events": {
      "1": [
        {
          "date": 123.2,
          "msg": "msg1"
        },
        {
          "date": 124.2,
          "msg": "msg2"
        }
      ],
      "2": [
        {
          "date": 125.2,
          "msg": "msg3"
        },
        {
          "date": 126.2,
          "msg": "msg4"
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
]
```

Aggregate query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$match": {
    "state": {
      "$in": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "state": "$state"
    },
    "this_path": {
      "$first": {
        "$concat": [
          "events.",
          "$state",
          ".0.date"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

"this_path" gets "events.1.0.date", but how to use this value, in another query(line), I would like to do like a string interpolation. Some thing like

```
...
"date": {
      "$first": { `\$${this_path}`}
...
```

so it become the "events.1.date" then "$events.1.0.date" then "123.2"

Comment: It is not readily clear what you want for a result.  Please post an example of a document showing the desired outcome of your query.

Answer (score 0):

you can define it by `let` just for example a fragment from pipeline:

```
                $lookup: {
                    from: contentCollectionName,
                    as: 'content',
                    let: {
                        parentId: '$id',
                    },
```

The id is taken from above matched documents, but it can be anything